# How to configure hypersonic db for Liferay portal 7?

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I used the configs/dev/local/portal-ext.properties file and this contains:

```
    # Hypersonic
     #
     jdbc.default.driverClassName=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
     jdbc.default.url=jdbc:hsqldb:c:/data/hsql/lportal
     jdbc.default.username=
     jdbc.default.password=
```

Still when I add content to the site none of the lportal files have been changed in the c:/data/hsql/ folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default configuration uses Hypersonic and creates the lportal folder inside *LIFERAY_HOME/data* path, see [portal.properties](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-impl/src/portal.properties#L1032-L1035)

But in some Liferay 7 testing I realized that lportal files are not written to file until you stop Liferay.

So try stoping Liferay and check the files after that.

**A last warning:** Hypersonic is not recommended for production use. My advice: never use Hypersonic, install Postgresql or MySQL and configure Liferay to connect to them.

Comment: I mean how can I run /point my tomcat to a different location for data path, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47218496/how-to-run-my-liferayportal-site-from-workspace