# How to run my liferayportal site from workspace?

Tags: eclipse, liferay, liferay-7

I have a liferay workspace that I deployed through blade successfully. In my workspace I have a bundles directory:

```
  > bundles
    > -----data
    > -------document_library
    > -------elasticsearch
    > -------hypersonic
    > ---------lportal.lck
    > ---------lportal.log
    > ---------lportal.properties
    > ---------lportal.script
```

At the moment when I run tomcat which is installed in a different location but locally , does not display the content from my bundles. How can I configure LR so it serves my webcontent from the bundles above and not the standard Hello world page?
Also how can I configure liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga5 so it points to the lportal files above?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own posts.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change following property in portal-ext.properties

resource.repositories.root=your bundle path

My liferay is located at

```
E:\liferay-dxp-digital-enterprise-7.0-sp4\portal-ext.properties
```

and my eclipse liferay bundle is at

```
E:\workspace\bundles\data.
```

Following is property from my portal-ext.properties

```
resource.repositories.root=E:/workspace/bundles
```

Comment: I am using liferay-ce-portal-tomcat-7.0-ga4-20170613175008905.zip but cannot find the portal-ext.properties file?

Comment: You can create this file (if not exist) from liferay root directory from where your liferay tomcat is running.